# How to convert .mat file into csv using python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have used this code first-

```
from scipy.io import loadmat 
data=loadmat(r"C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\HTS_C1_SN14_13.11.2019_02.mat")
print(data.keys())
```

and then i got this as an output-

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'EyePts_', 'JoyPts_', 'TrlNo_', 'M1EyeX_', 'M1EyeY_', 'M1Pupil_', 'M1JoyX_', 'M1JoyY_', 'cond_', 'RwdCue_', 'MagCue_', 'MLTrialStart_', 'MLTrialEnd_', 'TrialStart_', 'FixToggleON_', 'FixON_', 'AcqFix_', 'HoldFix_', 'Correct_', 'RewardONJ1_', 'RewardOFFJ1_', 'Abort_', 'EndOfTrial_', 'ITION_', 'ITIOFF_', 'STargetON_', 'AcqSTarget_', 'HoldSTarget_', 'SmRwdON_', 'SmRwdOFF_', 'LickCamON_', 'RewardCueON_', 'HoldRwdCue_', 'MagnitudeCueON_', 'HoldMagCue_', 'TwoTargetsON_', 'AcqRTarget_', 'HoldRTarget_', 'AcqLTarget_', 'HoldLTarget_', 'RewardONJ2_', 'RewardOFFJ2_', 'RewardONJ3_', 'RewardOFFJ3_', 'RewardONJ4_', 'RewardOFFJ4_', 'YRcue_pos_', 'WRcue_pos_', 'LT_pos_', 'RT_pos_', 'RT_col_', 'LT_col_', 'RCueCol_', 'JoyPosn_', 'LeftT_', 'RtT_', 'ReactionTime_', 'ReactionTimeP_'])
```

I am now lost, and i do not know how to convert this into a pandas dataframe and save it as csv.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try Using:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat 
import pandas as pd
data = loadmat(r"C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\HTS_C1_SN14_13.11.2019_02.mat")
data  = {k:v for k, v in data.items() if k[0] != '_'}
df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in data.items()})  
df.to_csv("example.csv")
```

Comment: it is giving me this error- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 data=loadmat(r"C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\HTS_C1_SN14_13.11.2019_02.mat")
----> 4 mat={k:v for k,v in mat.items() if k[0]!="_"}
      5 data=pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v[0])for k ,v in mat.items()})
      6 data.to_csv("IITK.csv")

NameError: name 'mat' is not defined

Comment: try now. I changed the variable name.

Comment: i think it worked but where do i find the csv file now? or how do i see the csv file? i am sorry i am just a newbie here!!!

Comment: oh wait, i now found it! thanks a ton for your help!!

Comment: @AnshBharadwaj if the answer is correct upvote it and mark as correct by clicking the tick under the down arrow