# how to deal with the following error while converting .mat to csv files?

Tags: python, matlab, csv

I am trying to convert .mat files into csv with the following code -

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
data1=loadmat(r"C:\Users\ansha\Downloads\OneDrive_1_830_2022\HTS_C1_SN09_all_08.11.2019.mat")
data1={k:v for k,v in data1.items() if k[0]!="_"}
df1=pd.DataFrame({k:pd.Series(v[0])for k ,v in data1.items()})
df1.to_csv("u1.csv")
```

but this error keeps popping up-

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:405, in Series.__init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    401 elif isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
    402     if len(data.dtype):
    403         # GH#13296 we are dealing with a compound dtype, which
    404         #  should be treated as 2D
--> 405         raise ValueError(
    406             "Cannot construct a Series from an ndarray with "
    407             "compound dtype.  Use DataFrame instead."
    408         )
    409 elif isinstance(data, Series):
    410     if index is None:

ValueError: Cannot construct a Series from an ndarray with compound dtype.  Use DataFrame instead.
```

Please help me to convert .mat file to csv. Also,what does the compound dtype mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! dtype refers to a data type object for python.  Compound data types are data types that can be constructed from fundamental data types (or other compound data types). More details: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-compound-data-types/

Comment: Looks like the error is due to the structure of your .mat file. If you are looking for a specific solution you should share the .mat file or explain it at least.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert .mat file into csv using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73528348/how-to-convert-mat-file-into-csv-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

What about data frames? Save the new data to a new vector with `data["mat file"]` and check the data structure with `pd.DataFrame()` so you can use it to create a CSV file while checking the information with the `variable.to_scv("pathname")` code.